# Modifying pointer value in function

Tags: c++, pointers

Can anybody point out why does the following code need char** pointer in the modify function. If i just pass char* and modify the value once the function call returns k has garbage value. Can somebody justify this?

```
char* call()
{
    return "fg";
}
void modify(char** i)
{
    *i = call();
}

int main()
{
    char* k= new char[3];
    modify(k);
}
```

Comment: How did this compile though ? `modify` takes a parameter of type `char**` and not `char*`. Also, use `std::string` instead.

Comment: Yes, please post code that actually compiles; otherwise it can be difficult to tell what you're asking about.

Answer (score 5):

When you pass something into a function, you pass it **by value**.  This means that the function operates on a **copy** of that thing.

This applies to pointers too.  If you pass a `char *`, then a copy of that pointer gets made; the original pointer is not modified.  If you want to modify the original pointer itself, then you need to pass its address, via a `char **` argument.

---

**Notes:**

*1. It's also worth pointing out that your code contains a memory leak.  You dynamically-allocate some memory, and then lose the pointer to it, which means that you can never `delete` it.*

*2. In C++, you should generally avoid passing raw pointers around like this, because it causes pain and confusion.  You should look into smart pointers.*

Comment: Worth noting that in C++ it generally gives more readable code to pass a reference to a pointer instead of a pointer to a pointer - but in C thats not an option.

Comment: More readable code yes.  The declaration can be fun though.  Let's throw in a template...

Comment: What if i modify the "modify" function program to take a reference to a pointer and pass the address while calling..Will there be a memory leak still?